# Android: How to move Dalvik cache BACK to internal memory?

Tags: android, dalvik, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, app2sd

I've used A2SD script to move the dalvik cache to a special partition on my SD card in order to use it as an extended internal memory. However I did it under a beta release of ICS on my HTC Desire, which does not officially support a2sd. Now I have several usability issues and I would like to move everything back to the internal memory.

Is that possible through a terminal emulator (I have SU credentials on a rooted phone)?

I've tried APP2SDGUI from the market hoping that it has reverse option, but it says it cannot start for some reason.

I know I am messing with stuff that's not supported or even tested, but if anyone knows any script / command I would like to try them out.

P.S.: [Here's a link to the script I've used](http://www63.zippyshare.com/v/83631202/file.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hard reset (pressing power button and upper volume key simultaneously at the time of booting the mobile) and chose factory reset.I hope this should solve your problem.